# Why the second time I run open() and write() in Python the same txt file nothing is written?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

Hey I am trying to write in the same txt file a few times in my program.

I have some other processes going on that's why I start a multiprocess to calculate some data and write it into the file. I close it afterwards and later on I have to reopen the file and write it in again. I also want to override the old date so I am using the following code

The first time it's working very well but the second(third..) time nothing is written into that file, does anyone whats the reason for this?

```
file_out = open("Daten.txt", "w")
file_out.write("%.2f  %.2f\n" %(distance, time))
file_out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're re-writing  the file again and again so use `a` or `a+` to append it

try this :

```
file_out = open("Daten.txt", "a+")

file_out.write("%.2f %.2f\n" %(distance, time))

file_out.close()
```

Comment: I already tried this, since I want to erase the old data i wrote

file_out = open("Daten.txt", "a+")
file_out.truncate(0)
file_out.write("%.2f %.2f\n" %(distance, time))
file_out.close()

but I still had the same problem. It's working the first time but after that nothing is written in the file